# How to set action for UIimage which is in coverflow?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimage, coverflow

Here is my code which i created array of images where it leads to another page by touching up an image..I got the coverflow of images but cant set action for image..can anyone help?...

```
[super viewDidLoad];

loadImagesOperationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSString *imageName;

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    imageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"cover_%d.jpg", i];

    [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forIndex:i];
    [imageName release];
    NSLog(@"%d is the index",i);

}
[(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setNumberOfImages:10];

- (UIImage *)defaultImage{

return [UIImage imageNamed:@"cover_1.jpg"];
}
```

here i've followed the following link tutorial to get coverflow..
http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/09/how-to-add-coverflow-effect-on-your-iphone-app-openflow/

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

if you need a way to react upon a tap on an image, then have a look at [this fork I made to AFOpenFlow](https://github.com/sdesimone/OpenFlow). You will see a new class, `SDSOpenFlowView`, which derives from `AFOpenFlow`, and a `SDSOpenFlowViewDelegate` which extends the original delegate protocol. It also supports shaking of the images and long pressure.

OLD ANSWER:

Set a delegate for your cover flow view, eg. if you do that inside of your controller and let your controller be the delegate:

```
coverFlowView.delegate = self;
```

then define this method

```
- (void)openFlowView:(AFOpenFlowView *)openFlowView selectionDidChange:(int)index;
```

in your controller: it will be called when the user selects a different page.

Comment: i guess what he need is an event to be fired when he tap on the image itself

Comment: @Omar Abdelhafith: thanks; I have just pushed to github an extension to AFOpenFlow I made some time ago to handle taps and more...

Comment: @sergio:i've added following code under and included particular viewcontroller too -(void)openFlowView;(.......)index;But no change in app...
    SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    second.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];

Comment: @Dany: you should instantiate the SDSOpenFlowView class instead of AFOpenViewClass and once you set the delegate and define the action method it should work...

Answer (score 1):

Find - https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/iphone/Classes/AFOpenFlow/AFOpenFlowView.m

You already have this event (touchesEnded even) in AFOpenFlowView.m, just customize it and do the needful.

Post comment if you face any issue.

Comment: i've added following code under and included particular viewcontroller too  '-(void)openFlowView;(.......)index;But no change in app... SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; second.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical; [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];'

Comment: Hey Dany, as you are using AFOpenFlow, Look into your code, you must have a AFOpenFlowView.m file, and you just need to code of navigate to the next page, in **- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event**  of AFOpenFlowView.m file